# What does "bit-bearing" mean?

Tags: meaning

Firstly, sorry if this is a very specific question.

I am trying to translate [A Declaration of the Independence of Cyberspace](https://projects.eff.org/~barlow/Declaration-Final.html) and I stuck at this phrase "bit-bearing":

> In China, Germany, France, Russia, Singapore, Italy and the United States, you are trying to ward off the virus of liberty by erecting guard posts at the frontiers of Cyberspace. *These may keep out the contagion for a small time, but they will not work in a world that will soon be blanketed in **bit-bearing media**.*

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything using Google but [one similar question at this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210857/what-does-state-bearing-mean). From the answer in at the link, I assume it means “media which uphold or to some extent control the way the bits operates”.

Thanks!

Comment: My first instinct is to say that it means *guided by a bit and reins, like a horse*.

Comment: Cyberspace is all about computers and computes *think* in bits. These bits (i.e., information) will soon be arriving in all types of media and it will be difficult, if not impossible, to prevent this information from leaking in no matter how hard you try to prevent it.

Comment: Interesting -- A professional programmer and computer engineer for over 40 years and I never heard that idiom before.

Comment: (In the US, at least, it would normally have been "... will soon be blanketed in digital media.")

Comment: (But, given that this is an excerpt from a longer treatise on the topic, I'm guessing that the author had worn out "digital media" and was looking for a "fresh" term.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my dialect of English this would refer to media that is predominantly digital (bit-bearing) as opposed to predominantly printed.

Comment: I've no doubt that's what the writer meant, but in *my* dialect of English it sounds really daft. Would anyone describe printed material (books, magazines, etc.) as *letter-, word-,* or *ink-bearing media?* Or pre-digital films as *celluloid-bearing?*

Comment: @Fumble The digital small press is the *bitty media* then, eh :)

Comment: @tchrist: Indeed - those small independents would be the ones the global players routinely take [shark-]byte-sized chunks out of.

Comment: @Fumblefingers; your examples of letters and ink are apt, but the "celluloid" one is backwards, the celluloid bears the images; it is more analogous to paper. Movies were previously "celluloid-borne".

Comment: @Brian: I guess you're right - I was carelessly thinking along the lines of the magnetic ***coating*** on the polymer base of an audio tape (which in principle could be called *magnet-bearing* media, except in practice it's not).

Answer (score 2):

*Bit-bearing* in this context means *bit-carrying*.  The media is digital—that is it *carries* information in the form of bits (Binary digITS - 1s and 0s).

Similar expressions: a *water-bearing* river, *gold-bearing* rock.

Comment: But it "bit-bearing" is a rather odd and obscure stand-in for "digital".

Comment: I take it as an attempt to be somewhat literary.

Comment: I take it to be more illiterary.

Comment: Maybe — it doesn't sound that strange to me, although semantically, I'd think a better rendering would be media-bearing bits—because bits carry the information, the information doesn't carry the bits.  The wires, however, really do carry the bits.